# python - is there a better way of writing this, shorter and easier to add more

Tags: python

I'm creating a set of string numbers to be matched with another set of string numbers

this is the long and hard way, is there a better or shorter way where i can easily expand this list to say 500 more

```
    a = i
    print 'grabing file',(a)
    #print (a)
    b = i+1
    print 'grabing file',(b)
    c = i+2
    print 'grabing file',(c)
    d = i+3
    print 'grabing file',(d)
    e = i+4
    print 'grabing file',(e)
    f = i+5
    print 'grabing file',(f)
    g = i+6
    print 'grabing file',(g)
    h = i+7
    print 'grabing file',(h)
    j = i+8
    print 'grabing file',(j)
    k = i+9
    print 'grabing file',(k)
    l = i+10
    print 'grabing file',(l)
    m = i+11
    print 'grabing file',(m)
    n = i+12
    print 'grabing file',(n)
    o = i+13
    print 'grabing file',(o)
    p = i+14
    print 'grabing file',(p)
    q = i+15
    print 'grabing file',(q)
    r = i+16
    print 'grabing file',(r)
    s = i+17
    print 'grabing file',(s)
    t = i+18
    print 'grabing file',(t)
    u = i+19
    print 'grabing file',(u)
    v = i+20
    print 'grabing file',(v)
    w = i+21
    print 'grabing file',(w)
    x = i+22
    print 'grabing file',(x)
    y = i+23
    print 'grabing file',(y)
    b1 = i+24
    print 'grabing file',(b1)
    c1 = i+25
    print 'grabing file',(c1)
    d1 = i+26
    print 'grabing file',(d1)
    e1 = i+27
    print 'grabing file',(e1)
    f1 = i+28
    print 'grabing file',(f1)
    g1 = i+29
    print 'grabing file',(g1)
    h1 = i+30
    print 'grabing file',(h1)
    j1 = i+31
    print 'grabing file',(j1)
    k1 = i+32
    print 'grabing file',(k1)
    l1 = i+33
    print 'grabing file',(l1)
    m1 = i+34
    print 'grabing file',(m1)
    n1 = i+35
    print 'grabing file',(n1)
    o1 = i+36
    print 'grabing file',(o1)
    p1 = i+37
    print 'grabing file',(p1)
    q1 = i+38
    print 'grabing file',(q1)
    r1 = i+39
    print 'grabing file',(r1)
    s1 = i+40
    print 'grabing file',(s1)
    t1 = i+41
    print 'grabing file',(t1)
    u1 = i+42
    print 'grabing file',(u1)
    v1 = i+43
    print 'grabing file',(v1)
    w1 = i+44
    print 'grabing file',(w1)
    x1 = i+45
    print 'grabing file',(x1)
    y1 = i+46
    print 'grabing file',(y1)
    b2 = i+47
    print 'grabing file',(b2)
    c2 = i+48
    print 'grabing file',(c2)
    d2 = i+49
    print 'grabing file',(d2)
    e2 = i+50
    print 'grabing file',(e2)
    f2 = i+51
    print 'grabing file',(f2)
    g2 = i+52
    print 'grabing file',(g2)
    h2 = i+53
    print 'grabing file',(h2)
    j2 = i+54
    print 'grabing file',(j2)
    k2 = i+55
    print 'grabing file',(k2)
    l2 = i+56
    print 'grabing file',(l2)
    m2 = i+57
    print 'grabing file',(m2)
    n2 = i+58
    print 'grabing file',(n2)
    o2 = i+59
    print 'grabing file',(o2)
    p2 = i+60
    print 'grabing file',(p2)
    q2 = i+61
    print 'grabing file',(q2)
    r2 = i+62
    print 'grabing file',(r2)
    s2 = i+63
    print 'grabing file',(s2)
    t2 = i+64
    print 'grabing file',(t2)
    u2 = i+65
    print 'grabing file',(u2)
    v2 = i+66
    print 'grabing file',(v2)
    w2 = i+67
    print 'grabing file',(w2)
    x2 = i+68
    print 'grabing file',(x2)
    y2 = i+69
    print 'grabing file',(y2)
    b3 = i+70
    print 'grabing file',(b3)
    c3 = i+71
    print 'grabing file',(c3)
    d3 = i+72
    print 'grabing file',(d3)
    e3 = i+73
    print 'grabing file',(e3)
    f3 = i+74
    print 'grabing file',(f3)
    g3 = i+75
    print 'grabing file',(g3)
    h3 = i+76
    print 'grabing file',(h3)
    j3 = i+77
    print 'grabing file',(j3)
    k3 = i+78
    print 'grabing file',(k3)
    l3 = i+79
    print 'grabing file',(l3)
    m3 = i+80
    print 'grabing file',(m3)
    n3 = i+81
    print 'grabing file',(n3)
    o3 = i+82
    print 'grabing file',(o3)
    p3 = i+83
    print 'grabing file',(p3)
    q3 = i+84
    print 'grabing file',(q3)
    r3 = i+85
    print 'grabing file',(r3)
    s3 = i+86
    print 'grabing file',(s3)
    t3 = i+87
    print 'grabing file',(t3)
    u3 = i+88
    print 'grabing file',(u3)
    v3 = i+89
    print 'grabing file',(v3)
    w3 = i+90
    print 'grabing file',(w3)
    x3 = i+91
    print 'grabing file',(x3)
    y3 = i+92
    print 'grabing file',(y3)
```

the second part of this code is here ---(xyz)-- string numbers 1 to 100000, basically part of a filename

```
   if str(a) == xyz:
       print (a)
    elif str(b) == xyz:
        print (b)
    elif str(c) == xyz:
```

this continues on and on where i have elif elif elif till 92 times and then i stopped :)

Comment: Just use a loop: `for filenum in range(i, i + 93):` and `if str(filenum) == xyz: print(filenum)`.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And do Google's Python class: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/

Comment: To close voters: stop being lazy. This is not "Unclear What You're Asking". The question couldn't be any more clear. Either find the right duplicate target or don't vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the python's [control flow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) structures, particularly [`for`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm) loops.

#### #1

```
i = 100      # Arbitrary Value
limit = 100  # Arbitrary Value
xyz = '199'  # Arbitrary Value

for num in range(i, i+limit):
    print 'grabing file',(num)
```

#### #2

```
if num == int(xyz):
    print num  # Do something.
```

Comment: why did you use int rather than str()--  just curious

Comment: `str(123)=='123'` and `123==int('123')` are equivalent. Just a preference really. @A.A

Comment: ok thank you.. im currently trying to implement ur suggestions. hope it works

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for`-loop for the first part:

```
for a in range(i, i + 93):
    print 'grabing file', a
```

and the second part is a simple `if`:

```
if i <= int(xyz) <= i + 92:
    print int(xyz)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dictionary.  The keys could just be numbers:

```
i = 3 #or some other number
d = {}
for x in range(0,92):  #you can also change the range to 500 etc
  d[x]=i
  i +=1
```

This creates a dictionary or a system of pairs in this case.  A key and a value.

In order to print the `Key` whose value matches `xyz` you can use the below:

```
[m for m, y in d.iteritems() if str(y) == xyz]
```

This part basically runs through your values looking for matches and prints the `Key`

Comment: thank you, for the suggestion.  trying your code in to my code. and will see if it works